# NumericUpDown controls linked dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, numericupdown

I have a label with an integer, and I have multiple NumericUpDown Controls.
How do I make it so, that the NUDs are collectively is limited to the value of the label?

So for example:

```
int_lbl.Text = "0";
NUD1.Value = "3";
NUD2.Value = "7";
```

So if I increase either NumUpDown, it should throw an error since it's ran out of integers to allocate. but if i decrease the NumUpDown, it should add the integers back to the label. And vice versa to update them dynamically during ValueChanged Event.

The idea is to adjust the other variables accordingly during ValueChanged.

I've disabled keyboard entry, so the user is only limited to the use of the Arrows.

Comment: Did you mix the first with the second example?

Comment: @Steve The examples above are just to provide an idea.
I'm not sure how to dynamically link them during ValueChanged event rather than hard coding it programatically.
The idea is to adjust the other variables during ValueChanged.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Your comment… _How do I make it so, that the NUDs are collectively is limited to the value of the label?_ … This is unclear, nuds are collectively what? Added together? What would be considered limited to a value? Using your example, nud1 is 3, nud2 is 7 and the value in the label is 0... _So if I increase either NumUpDown, it should throw an error since it's ran out of integers to allocate._ What does this mean? Why has it run out of integers? _The idea is to adjust the other variables accordingly during ValueChanged._ … What other variables?

Comment: You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)